# Насколько необходимы Custom Exception?

Tags: php

Я так понимаю, хорошим тоном является под каждый вид исключения делать свой собственный класс.

Если нужно отловить что-то определенное и по определенному обработать то все понятно. Но если мне это не нужно?

Выбрасывать стандартные исключения будет норм? Если нет, то в чем будет профит делать под каждое исключение свой класс, если у меня одна точка выхода?

Comment: В свои исключения можно добавлять нужную вам информацию. Если хватает уже существующего (линия, сообщение), то вам уже ответили ниже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я так понимаю, хорошим тоном является под каждый вид исключения делать свой собственный класс.

У меня нет такого мнения. Не нужно плодить излишних сущностей. Если решаемо и достаточно, то совершенно излишне - излишнее утяжеляет код и его понимание.

Принцип во всем, имхо, простой - эффективно и оптимально. Если что-то можно упростить за счет использования функции - хорошо, если что-то упрощается и структурируется с классом - хорошо. Все должно быть так просто, как это только возможно. Но не проще) (*Альберт Эйнштейн)